# How can I remove a vertical skip added by splittopskip?

Tags: spacing, tex-core, boxes

The following example splits a box with the setting `\splittopskip=2cm`. Everything works as expected. However I want to remove the vertical skip add by `\splittopskip=2cm` some steps later.

Is there an easy way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\def\exampletext{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text }
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=1pt

\newbox\boxi
\newbox\boxii
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setbox\boxi=\vbox%
 {%
    \hsize=8cm\sloppy
    \bfseries\huge\exampletext
 }

\splitmaxdepth0pt \splittopskip=2cm
\setbox\boxii\vsplit\boxi to2cm
\setbox\boxii=\vbox{\unvbox\boxii}

BOX \verb+\boxii+\hfill\fbox{\box\boxii}

\setbox\boxi=\vbox{\unvbox\boxi}

BOX \verb+\boxi+\hfill\fbox{\box\boxi}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

The provided solution of David works nearly as expected. But it gobbles the first line of the splitted box. To demonstrate the behavior I changed `\exampletext` and added one `TextA` which should be the first line of the splitted box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\def\exampletext{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text TextA Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text }
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=1pt

\newbox\boxi
\newbox\boxii
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setbox\boxi=\vbox%
 {%
    \hsize=8cm\sloppy
    \bfseries\huge\exampletext
 }

\splitmaxdepth0pt \splittopskip=2cm
\setbox\boxii\vsplit\boxi to2cm
\setbox\boxii=\vbox{\unvbox\boxii}

BOX \verb+\boxii+\hfill\fbox{\box\boxii}

BOX \verb+\boxi+ unprepared\hfill\fbox{\copy\boxi}

\splittopskip0pt
\setbox0=\vsplit\boxi to 0pt

\setbox\boxi=\vbox{\unvbox\boxi}

BOX \verb+\boxi+ prepared\hfill\fbox{\box\boxi}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\splittopskip0pt
\setbox\boxi=\vbox{\break\unvbox\boxi}
\setbox0=\vsplit\boxi to 0pt
\setbox\boxi=\vbox{\unvbox\boxi}
```

removes the splitopskip glue from boxi in this case (replaces it with 0pt glue)  although in general it will remove all discardable items. If however the box came from a vsplit originally then probably there is only the one discardable item at the top of the box.

The first setting `\boxi` ensures there is a break point at the start of the box, so when you vsplit, it splits there and discards any following glue, then adds the 0pt `\splittopskip`.