# mdframed everyline extended frame

Tags: mdframed

In the following MWE, I have used `everyline=true`.  Is there any way to ensure that the vertical distance between the bottom of the frame on Page 1 to the bottom of text to be the same as the vertical distance from the top of the frame to the beginning of the text? Same question for Page 2.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=5pt, everyline=true]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know I understand your question. Sorry. But the splitting point is calculated during the compilation.

Comment: Page 1: The vertical distance between the first line of the text, i.e. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ... and the beginning of the frame is fine. Let's call this distance d1.  On the same page, before the frame splits, the vertical distance between the bottom of the frame and the last line of the text, i.e. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, is not the same as d1.  This makes the frame look ugly.

Comment: You can set `splitbottomskip` and `splittopskip`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I have just tested with splitbottomskip=0.5\baselineskip and splittopskip=0.5\baselineskip options.  First page is fine now.  But it does not do anything on the second page.

Comment: You must set `splittopskip=1.5\baselineskip`. The first line has a height of `baselineskip` and you need some more. You can find a small discuss about this topic in my previous question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/how-can-i-remove-a-vertical-skip-added-by-splittopskip